# grabbing twitter info using API?

Tags: php, twitter

How can I grab twitter following, followers and listed info using twitter API with PHP?

Comment: Do you want to get the number of followers or their actual names?

Comment: number of followers number of following and number listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the short of it..

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=USERNAME");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'SOmehitn/3.2');
$ret = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);

print_r($ret);
```

Just like hitting any other RESTful API.